# when I active owl carousel then show horizontal scroll bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

When I active owl carousel then show horizontal scroll bar. Now what can i do.

**HTML**

```
        <div class="col-md-6">          
            <div class="testimonial">            
                <div class="single_testimonial">                        
                    <img src="img/client.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <p>Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects.</p>
                    <p class="client_name">Shiddikur Rahman</p>                         
                </div>                  
                <div class="single_testimonial">                        
                    <img src="img/client.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <p>Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects.</p>
                    <p class="client_name">Shiddikur Rahman</p>                         
                </div>                  
                <div class="single_testimonial">                        
                    <img src="img/client.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <p>Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects.</p>
                    <p class="client_name">Shiddikur Rahman</p>                         
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
   $(".testimonial").owlCarousel({
        singleItem:true,
        pagination : true,
        theme : "owl-theme",
    });

});
```

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle with all your codes and include the css too here

Comment: Solved problem. Problem was HTML markup. Thanks for your response.